# Why does my Linux laptop not use swap space aggressively even with high swappiness value?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap, wayland

I have around 8GiB of RAM on my laptop:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       6.9Gi       214Mi       381Mi       580Mi       182Mi
Swap:         7.9Gi       883Mi       7.0Gi
```

I have a 8GiB swap partition, but find that it is used very less until the system uses 7GiB or more of RAM. The swap usage was less than 100MiB and jumped to about 800MiB when RAM usage exceeded 7GiB. I am expecting swap usage to increase as I have increased vm.swappiness to 90. In my situation I am ok to swap aggressively - I find that when I run a RAM hungry program for a short while, my system is in swap death.

I am running Ubuntu linux 19.04 (wayland desktop) with kernel version 5.0.0-16-generic.

Comment: When running a ram hungry program you want a LOW vm.swappiness to prevent "swap death".

Comment: No, the behavior I am expecting is that Linux will swap out desktop processes to make room for a short burst of RAM needed by my programs that run only for a short while (such as running tests during development). However, I am finding that my computer is hung.

Comment: TANSTAFL - upgrade your swap to SSD.  Depwnding on your application, look into huge pages.

Comment: My swap is on a partition on an (2.5 year old) SSD disk. My question is simple - how do I get Linux to use more of my swap disk, giving me more room to run my programs?

Comment: Increase vm.swappiness to 100 and extend the size of swap on your SSD. While this will force stuff to go into swap faster I dont recommend it as it will have the stated outcome but this wont help you.